# What does 歯が欠ける mean?

Tags: words, expressions

I would like to know what does 歯が欠ける mean: Lacking teeth? Broken teeth?

Context: 人の幸せを素直に喜べないやつ理解出来なさすぎて、また歯が欠けた。

My translation:

I can't barely understand people who cannot honestly be glad for other's happiness, 「???」.

How would you translate the expression 歯が欠ける?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Seems to be idiomatic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an idiom, and また歯が欠けた means "my tooth was chipped again (because I clenched my theeth)". Although I haven't seen something like this before, I can imagine this person said this to express his uncontrollable frustration. Perhaps this is an exaggerated joke, and he did not chipped his tooth in reality.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! :)